# Seeking to determine land use based on lat, long using GeoPandas

Tags: python, wfs, geopandas, nlcd

For a very large number (>500,000) of points we want to determine the NLCD surface descriptor for the point's latitude and longitude.

I've used the following code to access the dataset:

```py
import pygeoutils as geoutils
from pygeoogc import WFS, WMS, ServiceURL
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

crs = "epsg:4326"
wms = WMS(
    ServiceURL().wms.mrlc,
    layers="NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48",
    outformat="application/json;type=utfgrid",
    crs=crs,
)
```

but then I do not know what to do next, or even if I am on the best path.

I'm fairly confident that I can use GeoPandas to find the closest tile to a certain point but I do not know how to create a dataframe containing lat, lon, and land use.

Comment: You might be over-engineering the solution. If the WMS service supports a query operation then you just need to ask the service what features are found at the specified location. I think you want to look at the `getmap_bybox` method of the WMS class in pygeoogc. You might still need to implement a UI but the query is relatively straight forward. https://hyriver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/pygeoogc/pygeoogc/index.html#pygeoogc.pygeoogc.WMS